# Evaluate a string that contains variable name on the fly in Python?

Tags: python

I have a string variable that contains the name of another variable

```
mystring = 'var1'
```

I seek to create a function that takes var1 as an input:

```
def myfun(var1):
    res = somefun(var1)
    return res
```

but instead of using the expression var1 directly, I want to use the string. So sth like this:

```
def myfun(eval(mystring)):
    res = somefun(eval(var1))
    return res
```

I know, normally the name of the function argument is irrelevant but in my case, it is actually not. Also wrapping the eval around the entire function definition cannot be done. Why? Essentially because I am building on other code which comes with this requirement. I know, it sounds strange but it is what it is

Any idea how to do this?

I tried solving it with eval() or exec() for only some part of the code but these did not work.

**EDIT**

Clarification. I want to declare a bunch of functions (lets say 2) that look like this

```
def myfun1(var1):
    res1 = somefun(var1)
    return res1

def myfun2(var2):
    res2 = somefun(var2)
    return res2
```

where the name of the arguments/outputs are important because the codes with which I want to use this use these names to connect these function in a graph (think that output of myfun2 shall be used in another function that uses res2 as input). I guess this has been implemented with inspect. It is probably not optimal but this is what it is. Now I want to avoid the c/p from above with a loop to generate these functions dynamically.

Also I cannot use a dictionary because the code I am building on assumes that all variables here are np arrays.

Comment: don't do that. Store your variables in a dictionary instead (name = key).

Comment: just dynamically define the whole function using `exec`, but this all seems totally crazy

Comment: i am sure the variable name is most likely not the requirement unless someone uses the `inspect` library way too much, and even then there would be many way around this such as wrapping one function inside another, so what is the requirement exactly ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: Would love to but the code I am building on asks for np arrays only.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Sure it is crazy but I tried anyway. But it does not work as "inspect" throws the following error "OSError: could not get source code"

Comment: @AhmedAEK: Yes, I think the code on which I build uses inspect heavily. I tried to clarify my question above. Not sure how this can be solved by wrapping a function around?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments, use a dictionary here. Something like this:

```py
var1 = 'blahblah'
my_dict = {"mystring":var1}

def myfunc(a_dict):
    res = somefunc(a_dict["mystring"])
    return res
    
# or

def myfunc2(a_dict, key_name):
    res = somefunc(a_dict[key_name])
    return res
```

Here, you would set `my_dict` and then you could call `myfunc2(my_dict, "mystring")` and it would give you `somefunc('blahblah')`.

If you always want to use the same key (which would make sense if you were planning that variable name before), you could use the first `myfunc()`.

Comment: Thanks! My initial question was not clear enough. The problem is that I can only have np arrays as argument and the name of these arguments matters because the code I am building on uses the name of the argument. I edited my original question to make it clear..

Answer (score 0):

Python has a function, `globals()`, which returns a dictionary in which all global variable names are contained as keys and the corresponding values are the values of the variable.

```py
def my_fun(variable_name):
    globals_dict = globals()
    if variable_name in globals_dict:
        value = globals_dict[variable_name]
        # Do something with value:
        print(value)
    else:
        raise ValueError(f'No such global varibale {variable_name}')

var1 = 19
my_fun('var1')
```

Prints:

```None
19
```

Comment: If a kid asked why a gun wasn't working, would you load it and give it back to the kid? Yes, what you wrote is correct, but it shouldn't be done. OP would be better off not doing that.

Comment: @zvone This is less of a loaded gun then using `eval`; it's just *reading* a value from a variable. I am sure you could manufacture some far-out scenario where this would propose a risk, but would it be a realistic situation? I am not aware of any inherent danger in this.

Comment: Thanks! I think my question was not sufficiently clear. I do not want to use a string as argument of the function but rather name the argument of the function based on the string. I edited the original question to make it clear